# issues with 'time' command

Tags: time, exit, status

I was trying to time the execution time of an application by using this '/usr/bin/time -p ./a.out'. This is returning 'command exited with non-zero status 1' but it is giving me the timing information. How can I get rid of this error. I know that this error code is related to the 'time' command.

Comment: Have you tried `/usr/bin/time -p ./a.out 2>/dev/null` ?

Comment: I've just tried this but it is not giving me the timing information at all...

Answer (score 3):

From the manual page of `time`:

> If COMMAND exits with non-zero status, time displays a warning message
>   and the exit status.

Comment: Indeed. Basically, @suzanne, this means that *your* program (I'm assuming it's yours, as it's called "a.out" :) ) is exiting with a nonzero status code, indicating an error. What are you returning from your `main()` function, assuming you're using C/C++? Try returning 0 (which represents success.)

Comment: Thanks Matt. It was indeed an error from my executable. I've put 'return 0' at the end of main method and now it works absolutely fine !! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Just use the "--quiet" option, $ man /usr/bin/time:

```
--quiet: 
              Do not report the status of the program even if it is different from zero.
```